# SQL Rank function

Tags: sql

I'm struggle with SQL RANK function. Can some help me figured this out .

its possible to get my desire column?

that's my rank query, last column its my output. i want achieve output from column 3

```
RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY col1 ORDER By col2)

col1 col2 "desired output" "current output"
A   1   1   1
A   1   1   1
A   1   1   1
A   1   1   1
A   1   1   1
A   5   2   6
B   3   1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY col1 ORDER By col2)
```

that was the answer, thx anyway